# Why merge commits that introduce same change are not omitted from log?

Tags: git, git-log

The `--cherry-pick` option states:

> **Omit any commit that introduces the same change as another commit** on the “other side”

For next git command I see next tree:

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --cherry-mark --boundary --left-right bc2820d...b8d09ce

<   bc2820d (openapi3) Merge branch 'openapi3_exception_handling' into openapi3
|\
| = 4e1e0aa Testcase for not_found/exception requests to api
| = b39673d 'not_found' templates should not be probed automatically. Only when fallback
| = a8677df Dump empty schemas and non empty data
| = 27db48f Implemente before_render hook
|/
<   aa60f0a Merge branch 'hide_temporal_interface' into openapi3
|\
| = 5dd02f2 Mutate current object after update
| = d58c0ab Install missed modules
|/
| >   b8d09ce (xtucha/openapi3) Merge branch 'openapi3_exception_handling' into openapi3
| |\
| | = b6362ad Testcase for not_found/exception requests to api
| | = dc926cc 'not_found' templates should not be probed automatically. Only when fallback
| | = 55dc88d Dump empty schemas and non empty data
| | = 8369185 Implemente before_render hook
| |/
| >   c03438d Merge branch 'hide_temporal_interface' into openapi3
| |\
| | = d534cc4 Mutate current object after update
| | = 1b6af27 Install modules required by MonkeyMan
| |/
| > a3b7230 Clarify schema
|/
o f5b06ed Assign some defaults
```

If I want to see only new commit I add `--left-only` option and get merge commits in output.

```
<   bc2820d (openapi3) Merge branch 'openapi3_exception_handling' into 
<   aa60f0a Merge branch 'hide_temporal_interface' into openapi3
```

This commits **introduce same change as another merge commit** on the "other side"

**Why these commits are not omitted?**

**UPD**
From the example above I expect only one line of output:

```
> a3b7230 Clarify schema
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The merge itself is considered to be on the left side of the `...`, which is also why in the graph output it is marked with `<` rather than `>`.

To eliminate merges from `git rev-list` or `git log` output, add `--no-merges` or `--max-parents=1` (these are two spellings of the same option).

Edit, re question edit: for "git cherry" and similar purposes, every *merge* commit is considered unique.  That is, it is never the same as any other commit, whether that other commit is or is not a merge.  (This happens for multiple internal reasons, the most significant being that a merge commit has more than one parent.  To compute a *patch ID*, Git needs to compare the child commit to a single parent.)

(Edit 2: the above claim might be wrong: `git show <merge> | git patch-id` computes a patch ID for the combined diff of the merge.  So two merges that produce identical combined diffs may produce identical patch-IDs and hence be considered "the same" by `git cherry`.  In most cases, though, the combined diff for a merge commit won't match the regular, not-combined, diff for any of the commits it merges, which means that in practice, the merges will appear unique in `git cherry` or `git rev-list --cherry-mark` or similar.)

Comment: If you notice the same merge is marked < on one side and > on the other. Those merge commits introduce same change thus must be marked '='. In the question I compare two branches which have merge commits.

Comment: I clarify a question a bit

Comment: Ah. Merge commits are treated differently from non-merge commits, when computing change-sets. In particular cherry-pick simply ignores or rejects merges unless you tell Git in advance which "side" of the merge you care about. So for `git log` purposes, all merges are unique, never the same as any other commit.

Comment: I compare branches before I do rebase. I also use `--preserve-merges` option while rebasing. Thus I care about how merges are shown. After checking the tree of the history I check which commits are added/removed. I do not use `--no-merges` option because I afraid that some merge commits may differ on compared branches. Unfortunately I do not know and can not imagine the internal reasons why git count merges uniq

Comment: If you want to get a patch ID for a commit, you can use the `git patch-id` command: run `git diff` on it, vs the appropriate parent, or `git show` if it's a single-parent commit. It turns out `git show <merge> | git patch-id` will compute a patch ID for the merge, using the combined commit, but because combined diffs omit some files, you'd want the diff against the correct parent anyway.